# Cannot get Blazor running with VS 2019 preview and 3.0 SDK

Tags: blazor

I've seen all of the earlier posts (from last year) about global.json and the net core SDK but I just don't seem to be able to get the basic Blazor template project running with either 2.1 or 3.0. I have Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.0 Preview 3 and 3.0.100-preview-010184 installed. The error is the well discussed `HTTP 502.5 Process Failure`.

Answer (score 0):

Nicely explained with workaround in [Exploring Blazor with Visul Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/exploring-blazor-with-visual-studio-2019/).